# date month not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, date

why is

```
 string date = string.Format("{0:mmddyyHHmmss}",
    DateTime.Now);
```

giving me 420813104204

shouldn't it be 040813... ?

I am trying to match
mmddyyHHmmSS

Comment: `mmddyyHHmmss` should be `MMddyyHHmmss` `ss is Seconds`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this instead

```
string date = string.Format("{0:MMddyyHHmmss}", DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Though that will work, it would be better if you explained why it works so that the person asking can learn something about it. In this case that mm is for minutes and MM is for months.

Comment: I explained it in my comment but when doing `string.Format` and you are using an `arg` of `DateTime.Now` the `ss is usually used for the seconds in this part of the string `HH:mm:ss` so he must use `MMddyy` caps on the `MM` depicting the Month portion of the DateTime.Now

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `MM` for month not `mm`, mm is for minutes not months.

```
 string date = string.Format("{0:MMddyyHHmmss}",
```

You can find more about formats [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
string date = string.Format("{0:MMddyyHHmmss}", DateTime.Now);
```

would give you the required format.

Check out [this link](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) for reference

Answer (score 0):

That's because `mm` is for the minute not months, you need to use `MM`. You can see the definition for [custom date time strings here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

```
string date = string.Format("{0:MMddyyHHmmss}",
```

Further, I generally don't use `string.Format` with `DateTime` objects because I've seen some anomalies when it comes to parsing them across different cultures. Leveraging the `ToString` method on the `DateTime` object for me has always been more reliable. That's just something I've seen - it also could be that I was doing something wrong with the `string.Format`. I wish I could build an example of that right now but I don't even remember what those anomalies are now - I just remember having problems so I switched.